# Trying to get response from REST request

Tags: java, android, rest, youtube-api

I have an Android app where I am trying to get a response a REST call that I have into another class file in my Android app.

Here is the class file that makes the REST call:

```
public class YouTubeVidIDs extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public String current_YTVidID;

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String subYTURL_0 = "https://sunnahboxservice.herokuapp.com/management/youtubeapi/liveStream?channelId=UCos52azQNBgW63_9uDJoPDA";
        String subYTURL_1 = "https://sunnahboxservice.herokuapp.com/management/youtubeapi/liveStream?channelId=UUCos52azQNBgW63_9uDJoPDA";
        String subYTURL_2 = "https://sunnahboxservice.herokuapp.com/management/youtubeapi/liveStream?channelId=UUCROKYPep-UuODNwyipe6JMw";
        String subYTURL_3 = "https://sunnahboxservice.herokuapp.com/management/youtubeapi/liveStream?channelId=UUCN_mfNT4sUszWKfi0Urjv-g";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(subYTURL_0)
                .get()
                //.addHeader("accept", "*/*")
                .build();
        try {
            String response = client.newCall(request).execute().toString();
            current_YTVidID = response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return current_YTVidID;
    }

    public void setCurrent_YTVidID(String current_YTVidID) {
        this.current_YTVidID = current_YTVidID;
    }

    public String getCurrent_YTVidID() {
        return this.current_YTVidID;
    }
}
```

I am trying to pull the result into another class file as follows:

```
YouTubeVidIDs newID = new YouTubeVidIDs();
            String YT_ID = newID.getCurrent_YTVidID();

            Movie movie1 = new Movie();
            movie1.setId(1);
            movie1.getId(1);
            movie1.setTitle("Masjid Al-Haram");
            movie1.setStudio("Mekkah, KSA");
            movie1.setDescription("Live Stream of Masjid Al-Haram");
            movie1.setCardImageUrl("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ZKjKucsPdzI/TudWC99CE_I/AAAAAAAAAD8/qvWdDtw5IW0/s1600/%2528393%2529.jpg");
            movie1.setyTubeID(YT_ID);
```

I get the following error when it runs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: software.blackstone.tvsunnahboxmenu, PID: 3514
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
                      at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.K(SourceFile:236)
                      at fpm.b(SourceFile:2715)
                      at fot.k(SourceFile:15217)
                      at vma.run(SourceFile:1051)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                      at com.google.android.apps.youtube.embeddedplayer.service.service.jar.IApiPlayerService$Stub$Proxy.e(SourceFile:473)
                      at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.K(SourceFile:233)
                      at fpm.b(SourceFile:2715) 
                      at fot.k(SourceFile:15217) 
                      at vma.run(SourceFile:1051) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

When I run it on a physical device - the spinner for the YT video just spins and spins and the video never seems to load and it does not return an error message at all in the app run window of Android Studio.

Where have I made an error, and what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: call newID.excute().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explain**

You're using `AsyncTask` incorrectly.

`AsyncTask`implements 4-step.

1. onPreExecute
2. doInBackground
3. onProgressUpdate
4. onPostExecute

If finished your doInBackground then call `onPostExecute`.

Therefore, you have to handled using `onPostExecute`.

***You must check the reference. There is a detailed explanation.***

**Solution**

> implement interface for handling event.

```
public YourClass implements IYoutubeTask
{
    //....

    public yourFunction()
    {
        YouTubeVidIDs newID = new YouTubeVidIDs(this);

        //excute asynctask
        newID.execute();

        // you can used to new YouTubeVidIDs().execute(); 
    }

    //....

    @Override
    public void onFinished(String YT_ID)
    {
        Movie movie1 = new Movie();
        movie1.setId(1);
        movie1.getId(1);
        movie1.setTitle("Masjid Al-Haram");
        movie1.setStudio("Mekkah, KSA");
        movie1.setDescription("Live Stream of Masjid Al-Haram");
        movie1.setCardImageUrl("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ZKjKucsPdzI/TudWC99CE_I/AAAAAAAAAD8/qvWdDtw5IW0/s1600/%2528393%2529.jpg");
        movie1.setyTubeID(YT_ID);
    }

    //...

    public interface IYoutubeTask
    {
        void onFinished(String YT_ID);
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
// Notice.
// you don't need AsyncTask<String, String, String>
// AsyncTask<[Params], [Progess], [Result]>
// Recommend AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> for your source code.

public class YouTubeVidIDs extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public String current_YTVidID;
    private IYoutubeTask handler; 

    public YouTubeVidIDs(IYoutubeTask handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String subYTURL_0 = "https://sunnahboxservice.herokuapp.com/management/youtubeapi/liveStream?channelId=UCos52azQNBgW63_9uDJoPDA";
        String subYTURL_1 = "https://sunnahboxservice.herokuapp.com/management/youtubeapi/liveStream?channelId=UUCos52azQNBgW63_9uDJoPDA";
        String subYTURL_2 = "https://sunnahboxservice.herokuapp.com/management/youtubeapi/liveStream?channelId=UUCROKYPep-UuODNwyipe6JMw";
        String subYTURL_3 = "https://sunnahboxservice.herokuapp.com/management/youtubeapi/liveStream?channelId=UUCN_mfNT4sUszWKfi0Urjv-g";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(subYTURL_0)
                .get()
                //.addHeader("accept", "*/*")
                .build();
        try {
            String response = client.newCall(request).execute().toString();
            current_YTVidID = response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return current_YTVidID;
    }

    // implements onFinished method.
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        handler.onFinished(result);
    }

    public void setCurrent_YTVidID(String current_YTVidID) {
        this.current_YTVidID = current_YTVidID;
    }

    public String getCurrent_YTVidID() {
        return this.current_YTVidID;
    }
}
```

**Reference**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

The returned String `current_YTVidID` is declared as a class member, the instance of the class that's created to do the work in `doInBackground()` is released after the method ran which includes all of it's parameters.

Try declaring `current_YTVidID` inside the method (doInBackground) - that should return the result as a String which is not related to the instance that handled it.

Comment: I did as you suggested and my getter and setter are now showing errors. What am I doing wrong (getter and setter are in teh same form as posted above)?

Comment: remove the getter and setter - they're no longer required.

Comment: did you call newId.execute(""); so that doinbackground works

Comment: @alfasin: yes I did and the app still errors out. How do I now get the resulting string from the class file I just changed (sorry to ask such a trivial question)?

Comment: It's hard to guess which error you're running into now. Please update the question with the current running code, the error that you're getting, full stacktrace if applicable and which line triggers the error.